# Recommended Image Sizes for Experience Cloud site

Tags: images, experience-cloud, component, experience-builder-page

Im currently building a Experience site using the "Customer Service" template.

I raised a case with Salesforce Support to ask what the recommended image sizes for the Customer Service template are. They informed me that all images should be 170px X 170px.

This doesn't seem right. For example - surely the Banner image wouldn't be the same size as the Topic image, or Company Logo?

[image]

[image]

All component image sizes are noted in this Salesforce doc: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities.pdf

However, there isnt a specific section on this doc where all component sizes are noted. They are noted sporadically throughout the entire document, therefore its impossible for me to make specific callouts given the volume of components listed. The only way I could find the sizes I needed was to CTRL +F, and search for each component as needed. Does anybody know of an easy to read definitive list?

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I deleted your answer and included that information in the question itself - this way you might get to a more useful answer.

Comment: Thanks @MattLacey